# stale element even if using WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium

I do not understand why I am getting this error :

`raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <a id="u153-popover-trigger--3926" class="udlite-custom-focus-visible browse-course-card--link--3KIkQ" href="/course/kafka-streams-real-time-stream-processing-master-class/"> is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed`

I'm using WebDriverWait twice to check if new page is loaded :

- If pagination link for the new page changes accordingly
- If the new page's course list div element is loaded

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    
    def waitForLoad(inputXPath): 
        Wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        Wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, inputXPath)))
    
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service_log_path='NUL')
    
    driver.get("https://www.udemy.com/courses/development/?sort=highest-rated")
    
    courses = []
    f = open("0udemy.txt","a", encoding="utf-8")
    page = 1
    
    try:
        waitForLoad("//div[@class='filter-panel--paginated-course-list--2F0x1']")
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("timeout!")
    
    while True:

        ## I also tried that : 
        #courses = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='course-list--container--3zXPS']//a[contains(@class, 'browse-course-card--link--3KIkQ')]")
        #for i in courses:
        #    f.write(f"{i.get_attribute('href')}\n")

        for i in range(16):
            f.write(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='course-list--container--3zXPS']//a[contains(@class, 'browse-course-card--link--3KIkQ')]")[i].get_attribute('href')+"\n")
    
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='udlite-btn udlite-btn-small udlite-btn-secondary udlite-heading-sm udlite-btn-icon udlite-btn-icon-small udlite-btn-icon-round pagination--next--5NrLo']"))==0 :
            break
    
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='udlite-btn udlite-btn-small udlite-btn-secondary udlite-heading-sm udlite-btn-icon udlite-btn-icon-small udlite-btn-icon-round pagination--next--5NrLo']")[0].click()
    
        page+=1
        try:
            waitForLoad(f"//a[@class='udlite-btn udlite-btn-small udlite-btn-ghost udlite-heading-sm pagination--page--3FKqV pagination--active--3BrK7' and text()={page}]")
        except TimeoutException as e:
            print("timeout!")
            break   
        try:
            waitForLoad("//div[@class='filter-panel--paginated-course-list--2F0x1']")
        except TimeoutException as e:
            print("timeout!")
            break
    
    f.close()
    driver.close()
```

I'm getting the stale error between page 20 and 80. My world record is page 78.

EDIT :

Thanks to arundeep, I can continue the script from where it got the stale error, using a try/except.

When I encounteer the error, I'm catching the exception, closing the driver, creating a new driver instance, get the page where I got the error, and continue the while loop from that page :

```
    except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        print('stale:', e, 'page: ', page)
        driver.close()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, service_log_path='NUL')
        driver.get(f"https://www.udemy.com/courses/development/?sort=highest-rated&p={page}")
```

I do get a stale error at every 10 page or so.
And I'm still wondering why the error happens.

I abandon the idea. Always getting duplicated course links.
If someone can explain me the stale error...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code? How many links were you trying to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went through pages 1 at a time and printed(you can use f.write). You need to add a time.sleep() so Selenium doesn't crash. This can go forever until it runs out of pages. Or if specify a if page==n: break. It can even go through the seleniums life cycle.

```
while True:
    try:
        courses=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='course-list--container--3zXPS']//a[contains(@class, 'browse-course-card--link--3KIkQ')]")))
        for course in courses:
            print(course.get_attribute('href')+"\n")
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='udlite-btn udlite-btn-small udlite-btn-secondary udlite-heading-sm udlite-btn-icon udlite-btn-icon-small udlite-btn-icon-round pagination--next--5NrLo']")[0].click()
        page=page+1
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        url=driver.current_url
        driver.close()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
        driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Wow! Didn't know that `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until` was actually returning the found elements !   And I never thought using try/except that way, continuing the script in the except.   I'm mostly trying to find a way to solve that without using time.sleep.  I don't understand why the element becomes stale at the `get_attribute` line